# Parse Object Not Found For Update Error

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform

On Parse I have a user, this user has an ID needed to start a messaging service with them called `messageID`. This `messageID` is contained in a separate class (Messaging) with class ACL set to public read and `write = true`, however the individual rows have their ACL's set to `publicRead = false` and `publicWrite = false`, so only the user it is pointing to can read or write to it.

My problem is that ever since having a pointer from the user to that private message field I get (what seems like) random `'Object not found for update'` errors when I am creating a comment or a post in my app.

For more information the post that I am creating has a pointer called `postOwner` which points to the user that contains a pointer to the message class. I think because the second pointer is to a private field to everyone except the user I am getting the error. This however does not explain why a post works sometimes and doesn't work others.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to update any parse table value that a time `ACL Permission` is require.`ACL Permission` is Read Write permission.
set `ACL Permission` before query save (get Call back) response.
like...

```
ParseACL groupACL = new ParseACL();

groupACL.setReadAccess(user1, false);
groupACL.setWriteAccess(user1, true);  

groupACL.setReadAccess(user2, true);
groupACL.setWriteAccess(user2, false);  

gameObject.setACL(groupACL);
gameObject.saveInBackground();
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what was happening on this. My problem was that the object I was pointing to had `publicRead` and `publicWrite` set to false. What I had to do instead was query for that object in cloud code using the MasterKey. It's not ideal, but it solved the problem. Hope this helps